# How can I share a variable within a Meteor template?

Tags: javascript, methods, meteor

Suppose I have a click event that calls a server method to query and return a product code stored in a variable `a`. I then want to use the variable `a` in another click event. Is there a way I can do this? If I just use `a` in the other click event, I get an undefined message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session works pretty effectively.

```
Meteor.call("someServerMethod", anArgument, function(err, res){
  if !(err) {
    Session.set("variableName", res);
  }
});
```

Then you can use:

```
Session.get("variableName");
```

Comment: If I print the variable onto an HTML page, will it stay there using your method? Thx!

Comment: Sessions persist except in the case of a HARD REFRESH. Look around the docs for this, you can also explore things like ReactiveVars and packages that extend Session functionality.